# Identify values based on date and limit

Tags: mysql

I have output in a list of values.

```
Name  Date of Entry
C1 - 1/1/2011
C3 - 3/3/2011
C2 - 2/2/2011    
C4 - 4/4/2011
C5 - 5/5/2011
```

For say the above list count is 5, i have cap count as 2, so any 'C's greater than 2 should be disabled and the Cs that are going to be disabled will be based on date of entry.

ie. take out the Cs that are older based on date (first entered into the system), in this case C1 and C2 should be enabled and C3, C4 & C5 should be disabled.

`select * from table order by date;` => This gives me C1,C2,C3,C4,C5.

`select * from table order by date limit 2;` => This gives me C1 and C2 which is great, but how do i know C3,C4,C5 need to be disabled.

I do want to identify C3,C4 and C5 need to be disabled.

Is it possible to do in a single query? Any mysql developers any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to select the names of the rows that need to be disabled, or do you want to perform an update on the table?

Comment: No update, just need to know the ones to be disabled.

Comment: Are the dates guaranteed to be unique? What should happen if there are three dates '1/1/2011'? Remove two of them at random?

Comment: Yes dates are unique, in fact its datetime 1/1/2011 10:10:12 so there will not be same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the date is unique, try this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    date,
    date >
    (
        SELECT MIN(date)
        FROM your_table
        WHERE date > (SELECT MIN(date) FROM your_table)
    ) AS disabled
FROM your_table
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Error code:1235

This version of mysql doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' I am using 5.2, i don't think this is related to version #, could be related the query syntax.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: Sorry, I didn't test it before. Try my updated answer. I tested it, and it seems to work.

Comment: This is very close, but its not giving me the correct answer.

1/1/2011
2/2/2011
3/3/2011
4/4/2011
5/5/2011

If min date is 1/1/2011, i need to fetch top 2 ie. 1/1/2011 and 2/2/2011 as  enabled & need to take out 
3/3/2011,4/4/2011,5/5/2011 as disabled. ie. someway of flagging 1 and 0 for those entries via select if(current row's date>min(date),1,0) from table; ie. combine min(date) and compare date value, i think i am getting the logic, not sure about the syntax.

Comment: ie 

1/1/2011 - 0 - enabled.

2/2/2011 - 0

3/3/2011 - 1 - disabled.

4/4/2011 - 1

5/5/2011 - 1

as select query's output.